# Extracting Data From Web And Converting It To Meaningful Information In Java

Tags: java, data-mining

I am doing research on a system that extracts data from web and converts it into something meaningful so that a layman can understand.

But I am unable to find even the starting point.

Can you please give me some guidance about where to start and what tools in java can help me to design and develop this system.

Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues: extracting data from web, and converting it into something meaningful. The first can be done using a [web crawler.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495289/what-is-a-good-java-web-crawler-library)

Then comes the part where you convert the data. You need to be very specific regarding

1. The type of data you want.
2. The way you wish to store it.
3. The kind of mining you wish to apply to it.

For example,

1. Weather information for people of Hogsmeade.
2. A database with min/max temperatures with humidity and rain/snow info etc.
3. Predicting rainfall on the basis of the weather for the last 40 years.

Try to provide some context if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the reply BuggyMan, I can give you an example, suppose I have to get the latest events that will occur in a particular region. So I should get the list of sites that host the latest upcoming events, get the data from there, some how relate the data with the event timing, etc and then represent it to the end user in a form of meaningful info.

Comment: You shouldn't have accepted the answer just yet, since it didn't solve your problem (and I think people are less likely to care about answering an 'accepted' question). Also, I did not understand "suppose I have to get the latest events that will accouter".

Comment: "suppose I have to get the latest events that will accouter" - upcoming events. And I just described the flow, but the problem is that "I know what to do but I dont know how to do" so can you please suggest me some tools that will help me achieve what I want?

Comment: You can use apache solr (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for the mining part. It has good tutorials. I have never done the data-from-a-particular-region thing, so I can't tell about that.

Comment: So means solr and mine data directly form websites?

Comment: Mining data from _all_ websites will be a problem, since that will be too computationally intensive. You should consider narrowing the sites that you crawl. Other than that, I think solr should help.